# Birt Report and How to display record on Excel using one sheet?

Tags: birt

I use a birt in my grails application. Currently exporting to excel works, but if let say:

- you have 100 records

it will:

- show 40 records in one sheet and you will end up having 3 sheets in your excel file.

I wanted to know how I can import them in one single sheet to:

- display all the 100 records.

I have Googled it. I can't come up with a clear solution to my IDEAS.

---

I use the following Code in my Birt:

```
def IRenderOption options = null
case ReportTypeEnum.XML:
    //TODO:
    options = new RenderOption(outputFormat: "xml")
    break
```

The emitter I use is :

```
options = new EXCELRenderOption(outputFormat: "xls")
optiions.setEmitterID("uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsEmitter") 
println "Report:"+ options.isEnableMultipleSheet()
```

Does anybody have any idea?
Example :
[image: sAMPLE rEPORT ON EXCEL]

Comment: Do you currently have hard page breaks (ie. deliberately starting new page breaks before the page is full), for example on change of group, in your BIRT report?

Comment: @MarkBannister i didn't know where those settings were set before or not , o tried to look ,i suspect if it is not with emitter then it will be on the options ?

Comment: Have you tried searching the rptdesign file for the string "pageBreak" ?

Comment: @MarkBannister nop Sir, i can only see     <list-property name="privateDriverProperties">
                <ex-property>
                    <name>MAX_ROW</name>
                    <value>-1</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>XML_FILE</name>
                </ex-property>
            </list-property>

Comment: @MarkBannister ,i think am approaching to solution with the following article http://biny08.blogspot.com/2013/06/spudsoft-excel-emitter-single-sheet.html and i found out that page break interval was set to 40 ? and now how can i make it unlimited.

Comment: From your link, it looks like the section of code that includes `((TableHandle)designElement).setPageBreakInterval(0);` is the key to resolving your problem.

Comment: @MarkBannister Excellent you almost got the solution ....thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was ain't to modify some code or to change emitters but ,simple as shown below
The real challenge could be setting this property on run time , by detecting the report Types,because you might not apply all paging stuff to all your pages ...

[image]

Thank you, Bini . 
Refer this web Blog which has all the correct answers.
http://www.biny08.blogspot.com/2013/06/spudsoft-excel-emitter-single-sheet.html#more

Make
         Page Break Interval = 0 ( for unlimited ) or your custome Value

and set
         Repeat Header to false

Done! you will see all your  record in one sheet . Awsome :) !

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for the answer to that question for months, and finally found it by myself:
there is no need to write code, just consider this:

The XLSX export makes as much sheets as there are root items in the TOC or in the first groupment of a table. if only one item, you will get only one sheet.

- in your design, create an empty group in your main table, with the following specifications:
- name: Root
- group on: null (enter just these 4 letter in the field)
- table of content: 'Customer list' (any text you may want)
  no problem if you have other groups, just place this one before the others (cut/paste)

Then you will get a TOC (table of content) with as first level, your group just containing the text you have defined.

This way, you also can keep the html view or pdf export with original pages, which is useful when you work with TOC for instance. Imagine having a 100 000 items population, you can create 3 groups:
- one null group with TOC text like 'Population'
- the second one containing just the first letter of name (you should get 26 items)
- the last one containing people names

then, you will have to manage only 100000/26=3846 items per sub group.

And for those who do want excel sheets, remember : the first group item count equals the excel sheet count....

Answer (score 1):

Click on the **data set**. Open Property Editor for the same data set.
Go to **Page Break** option and give **Page break interval** to maximum number. I tried and 2147483647 was the maximum number BIRT designer takes.

Set options as below.

```
Before = Avoid,
Inside = Avoid,
After  = Always,
Master Page = None.
```

Tick the Repeat Header if you want the header to be available when data overflows to next sheet in excel after 2147483647 rows.

Attaching the screenshot for reference.

[Click to open screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe5SS.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. Select the entire table
2. Go to Properties
3. Select Page Break
4. Set the Page Break Interval to 0

Done.